# proof that $Y$ follows normal distribution

Tags: probability, proof-verification, normal-distribution

I'm new to probability and studying multivariate normal distribution. The one thing I don't understand is the linear transformation of multivariate normal distribution.If the $X$ follows Normal distribution where $\mu$ is $0$

$$X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma)\propto \exp(-\frac{1}{2}X^T\Sigma^{-1}X)$$
And linear transform it by matrix $A$ and get $Y=AX$.

How do you proof that $Y$ follows a Normal distribution?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

More precisely, $X$ has pdf $f_X(x):=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\det(2\pi\Sigma)}}\exp-\frac{x^T\Sigma^{-1}x}{2}$. If $Y$ has pdf $f_Y$, the infinitesimal probability $f_X(x)dx=f_Y(y)dy=f_Y(y)|\det A|dx$. (This modulus of a determinant is the coordinate transformation's Jacobian.) Hence $$f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{|\det A|\sqrt{\det(2\pi\Sigma)}}\exp-\frac{y^TA^{-1T}\Sigma^{-1}A^{-1}y}{2}\\=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\det(2\pi A\Sigma A^T)}}\exp-\frac{y^T (A\Sigma A^T)^{-1}y}{2},$$i.e. $Y$ has a multivariate normal distribution of covariance matrix $A\Sigma A^T$.

Comment: sorry but i dont understand why you applied jacobian

Comment: @RecklessSerenade That's how multivariable integration by substitution works. Note my answer reduces in the univariate case to saying that if $Y=aX$ for some constant $a\ne 0$, where $X$ has pdf $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2},$$then $Y$ has pdf $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi a^2\sigma^2}}\exp-\frac{x^2}{2 a^2\sigma^2}$$(i.e. $X\sim N(0,\,\sigma^2)\implies aX\sim N(0,\,a^2\sigma^2)$). Well, that's already well-known; my answer just generalises it. The Jacobian is equivalent to the $a$ in $dy=adx$ in the univariate case.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you over and over, but why $|detA|\sqrt{det(2\pi \Sigma)}=\sqrt{det(2\pi A\Sigma A^T)}$?

Comment: @RecklessSerenade Because $$|\det A|\sqrt{\det(2\pi\Sigma)}=\sqrt{|\det A|^2\det(2\pi\Sigma)}=\sqrt{(\det A)^2\det(2\pi\Sigma)}=\sqrt{\det A\det(2\pi\Sigma)\det A^T}$$(where I've used $\det A=\det A^T$), which is $\sqrt{\det (A2\pi\Sigma A^T)}$.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now that makes sense