# Is it right to say that vectors $A_1 X$ and $A_2 X$ are independent iff $A_1A_2^\top=0$?

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, covariance

I am new to multivariate normals, so this may seem trivial. Let $X$ be a vector of independent, identically distributed normal random variables. I think that $A_1 X$ and $A_2 X$ are independent iff $A_1A_2^\top=0$, for the following reason:

Since $X$'s elements are iid, we can write $X \sim \mathcal{N}[\mu, \sigma^2 I]$, and so

$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Cov}(A_1 X, A_2 X)
&= \mathrm{E}[(A_1 X-A_1 \mu)(A_2 X-A_2 \mu)^\top] \\
&= A_1\mathrm{E}[(X-\mu)(X-\mu)^\top]A_2^\top \\
&=A_1A_2^\top\sigma^2,
\end{align}
$$

which equals $0$ if and only if $A_1A_2^\top=0$, iff $A_1 X, A_2 X$ are independent.

Is this proof ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculation itself is correct. But so far, it only shows that $A_1A_2^\top=0$ is equivalent to $A_1X$ and $A_2X$ being **uncorrelated** which, in general, is weaker than being independent. In order to deduce the desired property, you still need the argument that [$A_1X$ and $A_2X$ again have a normal distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3194301/proof-that-y-follows-normal-distribution) and that [normally distributed random variables are independent if and only if they are uncorrelated](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/609732/jointly-gaussian-uncorrelated-random-variables-are-independent).

Comment: Thanks, but I think I made a typo in the title: I wrote $A_1^TA_2=0$ but it should be $A_1A_2^T=0$ right?

Comment: In order to be consistent with your calculation, yes. But the argument is symmetric, so it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, you have

> $X$ and $Y$ are independent $\implies$ $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)=0$

but the reverse is not true in general.

Let's take $X$ a random variable with $E(X)=0$ and $E(X^2)<\infty$. Let $Y$ be a random variable that can have value $1$ or $-1$ with probability $1/2$. Then we consider $Z=XY$. Obviously, $Z$ and $X$ are not independent.

But: $$\mathrm{Cov}(Z,X) = E(X^2Y) - E(X)E(Y) = E(X^2Y)$$ As $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $$E(X^2Y) = E(X^2)E(Y) = 0 = \mathrm{Cov}(Z,X)$$

Comment: You need to exclude the case in which $X=0$ almost surely.

Comment: Obviously. This case is not very interesting, though, that's why I forgot to take it into account.

Comment: But the case in question is multivariate normal...

Comment: In the original post, the proof was relying on $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)=0 \iff X$ and $Y$ are independent, which is indeed false, as my example shown. This error is more general than multivariate normal. As pointed out in the other answer, for the case of multivariate normal, another argument velds.